# PHP cant calculate directory

Tags: php, directory

I got a small problem with my PHP webpage. I want to calculate the size of a directory, but I got 2 folders in them, that I don't want to include in the final size. I use following:

```
function foldersize($directory){
$size = 0;
foreach (glob(rtrim($directory, '/').'/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each) {
$size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : foldersize($each);
}
return $size;
}

$home_directory = "./files/" . $user_data['unique_id'] . "/";
$dir = foldersize($home_directory);
$dirdel = foldersize($home_directory . "del/");
$dirtmp = foldersize($$home_directory . "tmp/");
$userspace = $dir - $dirdel - $dirtmp;
```

When I test, which variable the server is able to return I get following result: The server is able to calculate $dir, but it seems to have problems with calculating $dirdel and $dirtmp. So it returns 0. Both folders, however, have files in them. I hope anybody can help me with that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have tried your code and I think is OK - except one small mistake, 
`$dirtmp = foldersize($$home_directory . "tmp/");` ... there is typo, double dollar, `$$home_directory` ... other results from function are fine I think